# How to integrate Skrollr with Angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, skrollr

I'm having troubles integrating the [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) in Angular2.

I've tried to include the .min version of skrollr right in the index.html and then in my component, I'm declaring it like this `declare var skrollr: any;` right next to the imports.

I'm able to `skrollr.init()`on `ngOnInit()` method and skrollr becomes available, but I'm having troubles to attach the data-attributes to the events. Can someone explain me how to bind those data-attributes (specific to skrollr)?
Thank you

Comment: I got skrollr working in angular2 by including the .min version and initializing it in `ngAfterViewInit`. For data-attributes I am using `data-80p` as in 80 %.